# default is not reached in switch case

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this:

```
if (IPAddress.TryParse(item, out address))
{
    switch (address.AddressFamily)
    {
         case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
             // we have IPv4
             break;
         case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
             // we have IPv6
             break;                          
         default:
             new ValidationResult("A monkey must fling something");
             break;
    }
    //return new ValidationResult("A monkey must fling something");
}
```

But if it is not an `IpAddress` it has to hit on the default:

```
new ValidationResult("A monkey must fling something");
```

but it even skips that line, if it is not an `IpAddress`? So how to make it work that if it is not an `IpAddress` that it hits the default statement.

Thank you

This is the whole method:

```
internal string Serialize(EditProductModel model)
{
    IpConditionRedirectValidation validation = new IpConditionRedirectValidation();
    XElement settings = XElement.Parse(model.Product.AuthenticationSettings ?? "<settings/>");
    XElement ipaddresses = new XElement("ipaddresses");

    if (IpAddress == null)
        return string.Empty;

    string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    lines = IpAddress.Split(new char[0]);

    foreach (var item in lines)
    {
        if (item.StartsWith("127") || item.StartsWith("192"))


            return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

        IPAddress address;// = null;
        if (IPAddress.TryParse(item, out address))
        {

            switch (address.AddressFamily)
            {
                case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                    ipaddresses.Add(new XElement("ipaddress", item));
                    // we have IPv4
                    break;
                case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                    // we have IPv6
                    ipaddresses.Add(new XElement("ipaddress", item));
                    break;
                case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.Unspecified:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
    settings.Add(ipaddresses);

    return settings.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Seems you forgot `return`

Comment: default case will be executed if all above cases do not match

Comment: It is really unclear what this code should do and what it does do. Set  breakpoints and start debugging. If `IPAddress.TryParse()` returns `false`, your `switch` is never hit, so your default won't be either...

Comment: So what actually happens if you test your code with an other protocol?

Comment: @Flat. You mean this: default:
                           return new ValidationResult("A monkey must fling something"); but that doesnt work

Comment: @CodeCaster. It works if it is a ipaddress. but so if I put this: 12. what is ofcourse not an ipaddress, then it doesnt hit the default. What is ofcourse strange. Because in the default I return an validationresult. So that an not Ipaddress is not being saved

Comment: Yes, maybe it is just a part of the problem but the line only creates a new object which is garbage collected later and has no other effect on the program flow.

Comment: No, that's not strange. `IPAddress.TryParse("12.")` returns `false`, so your `if()` is never executed.

Answer (score -1):

You do not actually do anything with the ValidationResult, you just `new` it.

And when you pass it something that is not an ip address, the `IPAddress.TryParse` fails, so you will never get in your switch.

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible: updated the answer to reflect the updated post.

Comment: ?? I realy dont understand you. What did you changed?

Comment: `IPAddress.TryParse` returns false, so the switch is not used at all.

Comment: ?? But where is you solution?? I dont see that. But oke, thx man. I solved anyway

Answer (score -1):

I solved, like this:

```
 foreach (var item in lines)
            {
                if (item.StartsWith("127") || item.StartsWith("192"))                
                    return new ValidationResult("IpAddress cant be saved");


                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IpCondition.IpAddress))
                    return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));

                IPAddress address;

                if (IPAddress.TryParse(item, out address))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("IpAddress cant be saved");
                }
            }
```

Thanks all